# undefined reference

Tags: c++, ооп

```
CMakeFiles/inheritance.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `A::A()':
/home/user/Ceph/ceph-master/inheritance/main.cpp:4: undefined reference to `vtable for A'
CMakeFiles/inheritance.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV1B[_ZTV1B]+0x18): undefined reference to `A::f1(int)'
CMakeFiles/inheritance.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV1B[_ZTV1B]+0x20): undefined reference to `A::f2()'
CMakeFiles/inheritance.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTI1B[_ZTI1B]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for A'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

У меня возник вопрос, почему у меня не слинковывается программа, выдавая ошибки, которые написаны выше.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
private:
    int x;
public:
    virtual void f1()=0;
    virtual void f1(int);
    virtual void f2();

    void f3();
    void f3(int);
    void f3(double);
};

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void f1(){};
    void f3();
    void f4();
};

int main() {
    B b;
    int x;
    b.f1();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С точки зрения формальной спецификации языка С++ (Правило Одного Определения, One Definition Rule), все функции, которые *используются* (odr-used) в С++ программе, должны быть *определены*. Не-pure виртуальные функции в С++ программе всегда безусловно, по определению считаются *используемыми*, независимо от того, вызываются ли они в программе или нет.

Таким образом в вашей программе есть функции `A::f1(int)` и `A::f2()`, которые *используются*. Однако определить вы их забыли. Поэтому и возникает ошибка.

Функции `f3` и `f4` в программе не используются, поэтому для них определений не требуется.

Answer (score 2):

Ну вот смотрите - у вас есть абстрактный класс `A`. Да, вы не можете создать его экземпляр, но его таблицу виртуальных функций компилятору создать нужно.

В нее надо записать адреса всех виртуальных функций, объявленных в `A`. Про `f1()` сказано, что ее не будет - типа, напиши туда нулевой адрес. А про `f1(int)` и `f2()` - нет, там должны быть реальные адреса. Чтоб их получить, компилятору нужно скомпилировать их определения. "Глядь - ан их и нетути!" (с)

Вот он вам и пожаловался...

К функциям `f3` сказанное не относится - они не виртуальные.

Answer (score 1):

У вас не определены эти функции а только объявлены.  Их нужно либо объявить либо сделать чисто виртуальными.